# Создать класс который наследует Button и добавить несколько полей

Tags: android, android-button

я хочу создать класс который наследует Button и добавить несколько полей.
У меня выдает ошибку
[image: я попытался наследовать но у меня выдает ошибку]

Comment: желательно прикрепить саму ошибку, и текстовую информацию лучше прикреплять в виде текста а не картинки :)

Comment: Не хватает конструкторов.

Comment: Он подчеркивает потому, что предлагает наследоваться от `appcompat.Button`. Это можно игнорировать - все будет работать. Только поведение на разных API может быть разное (при смене на аппкомпат тоже разное, но диаметрально наоборот) - поэтому желательно проверить на старых/новых устройствах